# How to fix "Use of undefined constant" notices using a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am working on some old projects. Some variables are incorrectly defined, and so we are getting the following error message:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant `xyz`

For example:

```
$name = $_REQUEST[name];
```

There is a solution for this:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

But this occurs in many places throughout the project, so it is very difficult to find and replace.

Is there any regular expression that I can use to search and replace with proper name?

I tried using the following regex, but it's working correctly for all cases:

```regex
\$[A-Za-z_]\w+\[)(\b[A-Za-z_]\w+\b)(\])
```

How would I write the correct regex for this task?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to replace single quote in array if there is no single quote .

Comment: did you want to enclose the text inside `[]` with single quotes?

Comment: An example would be better.

Comment: As i asked if there var $_REQUEST[name]  then it should be replace with $_REQUEST['name']

Comment: did you want the output like this `$name = $_REQUEST['name'];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex will enclose text inside `[]` with single quotes only if there is no single quotes present inside `[]`,

```
\[((?!')[^]]*)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iD7jS4)

Your php code would be,

```
<?php
$string = '$name = $_REQUEST[name];';
$pattern = "/\[((?!')[^]]*)\]/i";
$replacement = "['$1']";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a few of these errors appear after upgrading a production server to use PHP 7.2 for a legacy project.

Here's the regex I wrote to identify undefined constant errors:

```
\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\[[a-z]+\]
```

I fixed the occurrences by hand, but the replacement pattern will be something along the lines of:

```
\$$1['$2']
```

Also it's worth mentioning that PHP doesn't raise an error for the following example (as it is within a double-quoted string):

```
"... WHERE id = $_POST[id]"
```

Comment: Importantly, while "... WHERE id = $_POST[id]" doesn't get a warning/error in PHP 7.2+,  the version of the double-quoted string with a single quoted index, "... WHERE id = $_POST['id']" used in PHP context will cause a parse error.  So whether the single quotes are required or are prohibited is dependent on context (in string or not, in PHP mode or not).